# How much memory(MB) can the vector variable occupy in enclave of Intel sgx?

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2017, sgx, enclave

I want to immigrate [PageRank](https://github.com/louridas/pagerank) algorithm in the sgx enclave. The algorithm uses vector to save the edge relationship and matrix.

```
vector<size_t> num_outgoing; // number of outgoing links per column
vector< vector<size_t> > rows; // the rowns of the hyperlink matrix
map<string, size_t> nodes_to_idx; // mapping from string node IDs to numeric
map<size_t, string> idx_to_nodes; // mapping from numeric node IDs to string
vector<double> pr; // the pagerank table
```

The application runs well when it stores less than 9000 edges. Once it increases to 10000 edges or more, the application crushes, and throws out an unhandled exception[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvPy1.png)
. I also run the same code outside the enclave, it runs well when it stores 90000 edges.

By debugging, I found the application fails at the places below.

```
if (rows.size() <= max_dim) {
    max_dim = max_dim + 1;
    rows.resize(max_dim);
    if (num_outgoing.size() <= max_dim) {
        num_outgoing.resize(max_dim);
    }
}
```

However, the variable 'rows' cannot be resized larger once it owns 13896 element. I'm confused that 'rows' only occupies about 300kb and 'num_outgoing' only occupies about 100kb. It's far less than the allow size. There is 128MB space in total for the enclave application.

My enclave config file is listed as follows. I try to change the value of StackMaxSize, however, it seems useless.

```
<EnclaveConfiguration>
    <ProdID>0</ProdID>
    <ISVSVN>0</ISVSVN>
    <StackMaxSize>0x400000</StackMaxSize>
    <HeapMaxSize>0x100000</HeapMaxSize>
    <TCSNum>1</TCSNum>
    <TCSPolicy>1</TCSPolicy>
    <DisableDebug>0</DisableDebug>
    <MiscSelect>0</MiscSelect>
    <MiscMask>0xFFFFFFFF</MiscMask>
    <EnableKSS>0</EnableKSS>
    <ISVEXTPRODID_H>0</ISVEXTPRODID_H>
    <ISVEXTPRODID_L>0</ISVEXTPRODID_L>
    <ISVFAMILYID_H>0</ISVFAMILYID_H>
    <ISVFAMILYID_L>0</ISVFAMILYID_L>
</EnclaveConfiguration>
```

The format of the input edge is shown as below. The first number is the "from" node, the second number is the "to" node

```
1 0
2 0
3 1
4 3
5 4
6 0
7 1
8 0
9 1
10 0
```

I wonder how to config enclave to make it allow bigger vector variable? The problem exists on both win10 and ubuntu.

Comment: "There is 128MB space in total for the enclave application." [For the entire system.](https://software.intel.com/content/dam/develop/external/us/en/documents/enclave-measurement-tool-intel-sgx-737361.pdf) Of which 96MB is shared among all enclaves as a page cache. While linux can in theory use more windows is very restricted on this. Intel highly recommends you are a "good neighbor" and limit usage while in the enclave as you're stealing from other enclaves when you use more.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, the above information is quite useful which doesn't exist on "Intel SGX SDK Developer Reference for Windows OS.pdf" or the coressponding linux version. Actuclly, this is the first time i get to know that only 96MB memory can be allocated by the user. Even with the above limitation, my confusion still exists for that i actually runs only one enclave application. In this situaiton, my problem maybe turns to how to make the only one enclave use as much memory as it can, and less than 96MB, for example 90MB. The application can only use less than 1MB now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All seems like you are running out of memory. The memory limits (stack and heap) are set in the config file using `StackMaxSize` and `HeapMaxSize` (see [Developer Reference](https://download.01.org/intel-sgx/latest/linux-latest/docs/Intel_SGX_Developer_Reference_Linux_2.15_Open_Source.pdf) for details). The size of the EPC (128MB or 256MB) has nothing to do with it. Here, you are not bounded by the EPC size but by the heap and stack.

Increasing the stack size does not change anything because dynamically allocated memory resides on heap. In turn, you should be looking at the max heap size. Currently, you have it set to `0x100000` (=1MB), which is quickly used up by your data. Try increasing it and see if you can accommodate larger vectors.

I think on Windows your enclave has to entirely fit into EPC but on Linux you can create enclaves with tens of GBs. Be aware that once your (Linux) enclave memory usage exceeds ~90 MB you will start noticing EPC paging and, with it, a huge performance degradation.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, the solution indeed works for my question. On win10, the program can occupy 83MB, and on ubuntu 18.04, it can occupy at least 4GB. But i wonder why there exists the difference between windows and ubuntu. And under my test, i find that the program with same scale, runs faster on ubuntu than win10, do u have any idea of this situation? Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: The Ubuntu SGX driver implements EPC paging and the Windows driver does not. 
So on Ubuntu you can over-allocate the EPC and the exceeded memory will be swapped to main memory (similarly to disk swapping for main memory). Search for EWB and ELDU x86 instructions for more details. 
The Windows driver does not support paging so if you over-allocate the EPC your program fails due to out of memory.
I cannot say anything about the performance of Windows vs. Ubuntu SGX driver. I am also not aware of any benchmark of these two. You would need to benchmark them yourself.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, it's very helpful. I found the mode used for program results in the performance difference. On win10, using debug mode will bring huge overhead compared to ubuntu. When changing the mode from debug to prerelease, the performance difference is not obvious.

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept the answer if it solved the issue you originally asked about.

Answer (score 0):

SGX CPUs (before Icelake) have a limited EPC, this is 128M for CPUs like Skylake, but you can also get 256M with Xeon E-2200. This does *not* mean that your application cannot use more memory, it simply means that the hardware-accelerated memory range is limited. Pages that don't fit into the EPC are swapped to non-EPC memory (at a considerable performance cost), however this is only implemented in the linux driver.

So, you can set the enclave heap to something much larger like 2G. What you'll see is slower startup time (that 2G must be completely initialized), and if your compute's memory access pattern is scattered in that 2G range then you'll see extremely degraded performance. So try to keep your access patterns local, use sequential/scanning like operations etc, the usual considerations for cache-friendly compute.

Regarding your actual issue, it could be that you're running out of the allocated heap, and that vector just happens to be the "last straw". Remember that the heap must contain not only these datastructures but also the code itself. If you're parsing the input from some serialized format then it could be that the serialized bytes are still retained in memory, if you have other state then that also uses memory, there can be many sources of extraneous usage. If you're using the Intel SDK then I'd recommend compiling in simulation mode, or just link your application into a non-SGX ELF and use usual memory debugging tools to track memory usage.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i didn't understand for the first time, and now i kind of understand, thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

Altough the other answers are perfectly correct, Intel recently increased the memory limit to up to 1Tb, see [here](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Software-Guard-Extensions/How-Intel-support-1-Terabyte-enclave-size/td-p/1290737) for more info.

Comment: This answer is unrelated to the question. Before Intel supported enclaves up to 32 or 64 GB (I think) but if the user sets the heap to 1 MB then even support for 1 TB enclaves won't fix the problem.